# Proving a bijection in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Be $\rho > 0, \alpha < \beta$, with $\rho\alpha,\rho\beta,\alpha,\beta \in [-\pi,\pi]$. Prove that $z \rightarrow z^{\rho}$ is a bijection of $\Omega_1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C^*}: \alpha < arg \ z < \beta \}$ in $\Omega_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C^*}: \rho\alpha < arg \ z < \rho\beta \}$

What I've thought is to work  with the exponential $e^{\rho \ log \ z}$ instead of $z^{\rho}$ but I don't find the manner of proving there is a bijection. Cound you take me a hand?

PD: Could you help too with this problem? [Mapping exponential function to complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531492/mapping-exponential-function-to-complex-plane)

Comment: Why $\frac{z}{|z|} = arg(z)$?

Comment: Should have been $e^{i \arg z}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the map $f(re^{i\theta}) =  r^{\rho}e^{i\rho\theta}$, with inverse $g(re^{i\theta}) = r^{1 \over \rho}e^{i{\theta \over \rho}}$.